# Error while exporting inference graph in tensorlfow object detection api

Tags: python, tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, object-detection-api

Hi I am doing `tensorflow object detection api`. I have followed all major instructions in the repo and it had been working fine until now.But some weird error is starting to pop upm suddenly. I was using `fast rcnn` earlier and now switched to `ssd mobile v2 coco`.

While generating inference graph using command

```
python export_inference_graph.py --input_type image_tensor --pipeline_config_path training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config --trained_checkpoint_prefix training/model.ckpt-10250 --output_directory inference_graph
```

I get the following errror:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1356, in _do_call
>       return fn(*args)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1341, in _run_fn
>       options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1429, in _call_tf_sessionrun
>       run_metadata) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key Conv/biases
>   not found in checkpoint    [[{{node save/RestoreV2}}]]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1286, in restore
>       {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 950, in run
>       run_metadata_ptr)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1173, in _run
>       feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _do_run
>       run_metadata)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1370, in _do_call
>       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message) tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key Conv/biases
>   not found in checkpoint    [[node save/RestoreV2 (defined at
>   /home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection/exporter.py:331)
>   ]]
>
> Original stack trace for 'save/RestoreV2':   File
>   "export_inference_graph.py", line 162, in 
>       tf.app.run()   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
>   line 40, in run
>       _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)   File
>   "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py",
>   line 299, in run
>       _run_main(main, args)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py",
>   line 250, in _run_main
>       sys.exit(main(argv))   File "export_inference_graph.py", line 158, in main
>       write_inference_graph=FLAGS.write_inference_graph)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection/exporter.py",
>   line 497, in export_inference_graph
>       write_inference_graph=write_inference_graph)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection/exporter.py",
>   line 426, in _export_inference_graph
>       trained_checkpoint_prefix=checkpoint_to_use)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection/exporter.py",
>   line 331, in write_graph_and_checkpoint
>       tf.import_graph_def(inference_graph_def, name='')   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py",
>   line 507, in new_func
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py",
>   line 443, in import_graph_def
>       _ProcessNewOps(graph)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py",
>   line 236, in _ProcessNewOps
>       for new_op in graph._add_new_tf_operations(compute_devices=False):  # pylint: disable=protected-access   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 3751, in _add_new_tf_operations
>       for c_op in c_api_util.new_tf_operations(self)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 3751, in 
>       for c_op in c_api_util.new_tf_operations(self)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 3641, in _create_op_from_tf_operation
>       ret = Operation(c_op, self)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 2005, in **init**
>       self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1296, in restore
>       names_to_keys = object_graph_key_mapping(save_path)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1614, in object_graph_key_mapping
>       object_graph_string = reader.get_tensor(trackable.OBJECT_GRAPH_PROTO_KEY)   File
>   "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 678, in get_tensor
>       return CheckpointReader_GetTensor(self, compat.as_bytes(tensor_str))
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Key
>   _CHECKPOINTABLE_OBJECT_GRAPH not found in checkpoint
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "export_inference_graph.py",
>   line 162, in 
>       tf.app.run()   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
>   line 40, in run
>       _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)   File
>   "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py",
>   line 299, in run
>       _run_main(main, args)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py",
>   line 250, in _run_main
>       sys.exit(main(argv))   File "export_inference_graph.py", line 158, in main
>       write_inference_graph=FLAGS.write_inference_graph)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection/exporter.py",
>   line 497, in export_inference_graph
>       write_inference_graph=write_inference_graph)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection/exporter.py",
>   line 426, in _export_inference_graph
>       trained_checkpoint_prefix=checkpoint_to_use)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection/exporter.py",
>   line 335, in write_graph_and_checkpoint
>       saver.restore(sess, trained_checkpoint_prefix)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1302, in restore
>       err, "a Variable name or other graph key that is missing") tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Restoring from
>   checkpoint failed. This is most likely due to a Variable name or other
>   graph key that is missing from the checkpoint. Please ensure that you
>   have not altered the graph expected based on the checkpoint. Original
>   error:
>
> Key Conv/biases not found in checkpoint    [[node save/RestoreV2
>   (defined at
>   /home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection/exporter.py:331)
>   ]]
>
> Original stack trace for 'save/RestoreV2':   File
>   "export_inference_graph.py", line 162, in 
>       tf.app.run()   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py",
>   line 40, in run
>       _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)   File
>   "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py",
>   line 299, in run
>       _run_main(main, args)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py",
>   line 250, in _run_main
>       sys.exit(main(argv))   File "export_inference_graph.py", line 158, in main
>       write_inference_graph=FLAGS.write_inference_graph)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection/exporter.py",
>   line 497, in export_inference_graph
>       write_inference_graph=write_inference_graph)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection/exporter.py",
>   line 426, in _export_inference_graph
>       trained_checkpoint_prefix=checkpoint_to_use)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/object_detection/exporter.py",
>   line 331, in write_graph_and_checkpoint
>       tf.import_graph_def(inference_graph_def, name='')   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py",
>   line 507, in new_func
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py",
>   line 443, in import_graph_def
>       _ProcessNewOps(graph)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py",
>   line 236, in _ProcessNewOps
>       for new_op in graph._add_new_tf_operations(compute_devices=False):  # pylint: disable=protected-access   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 3751, in _add_new_tf_operations
>       for c_op in c_api_util.new_tf_operations(self)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 3751, in 
>       for c_op in c_api_util.new_tf_operations(self)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 3641, in _create_op_from_tf_operation
>       ret = Operation(c_op, self)   File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/my_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 2005, in **init**
>       self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

Actually it had been working rightly all the time cant figure what happenned  now. I tried with fast rcnn as well(which was working earlier) but it has also started failing

Here is config file.I am doing it for 2 classes currently

```
# Faster R-CNN with Inception v2, configured for Oxford-IIIT Pets Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 2
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 600
        max_dimension: 1024
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_inception_v2'
      first_stage_features_stride: 16
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0002
          schedule {
            step: 1
            learning_rate: .0002
          }
          schedule {
            step: 900000
            learning_rate: .00002
          }
          schedule {
            step: 1200000
            learning_rate: .000002
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/user/Downloads/Data_Science/Git/models/research/object_detection/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: false
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 200000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
}


train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/user/Downloads/Data_Science/Git/models/research/object_detection/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/home/user/Downloads/Data_Science/Git/models/research/object_detection/training/labelmap.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 67
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/test.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "C:/tensorflow1/models/research/object_detection/training/labelmap.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

Found [one](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1836) or [two](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/5003) similar errors in github.But its of no use. Any help would be appreciated.If you need any more information,please leave a comment.Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your model `training/model.ckpt-10250` is a `faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets` model? The error `NotFoundError: Key Conv/biases not found in checkpoint [[{{node save/RestoreV2}}]]` implies that it cannot recover `Conv/biases` from the checkpoint.

Alternatively make sure that you are using TF version that is supported by the object detection framework. You can find all releases [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/releases).

Comment: I am sure with TF version as I was using it all this time.same with the case of fast rcnn